# Use of ß (“eszett”) in Latin text

Tags: new-latin, orthography, spelling, ligatures

I am translating a medical text from the late 16th century. The author is Swiss. The text uses the *ß* character (like the German [eszett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F)).

Example:

> toti amplißimo conseßui

Is this character being used in place of a double s?

Earlier in the text, a double *s* is used expressly:

> Veru maioris doctrinae capessendae

What is the difference in usage between *ss* and *ß?*

Sample images:
Eszett
[image: Eszett example]

Double s
[image: Double s example]

Comment: This usage is mentioned in the [Wikipedia article for *eszett*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%9F#Other_languages). It doesn't have any sources, though, so I don't want to post that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, I saw the wikipedia entry, but I wondered if light could be shed on the difference in uses because I cannot find any pattern to when "ß" and "ss" are applied: in the wikipedia entry, it gives "eße" as an example, but in my text, two esses are used for the same word.

Comment: My suspicion is that this was more of a typographical decision than an orthographical one, and that there were no firm rules in place about which to use. The eszett is just a combination of the long and short s. Again, though, that's just my hunch.

Comment: The word in your first example is consessui. The "n" is indicated by the squiggle over the "o".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The modern German roman-type *ß* was developed at the end of the 19<sup>th</sup> century as an analogue of the blackletter *ß,* which was a ligature of *ſ* and *z* (which is reflected in its name) that had slowly acquired letter status and looked distinctively different from your *ſs* (more like *ſʒ*). Some of the new *ß* designs may have been inspired by your *ſs* and similar forms. However, at your time, no German letter *ß* with that form existed.

What you have in your text, is a ligature of the long *s (ſ)* and the round *s (s).* In my experience, in most languages there was considerable arbitrariness in the usage of *s* and *ſ* at that time.

What can be said for sure is that *ſ* was used at the beginning of words and *s* was used at the end. In every other case the distinction may depend on whether the *s* is located after the vowel of its syllable, at the end of a morpheme, and what letter is following it. The distinction may be also be covered by what was typographically nice or available¹. The blog [Babelstone](http://babelstone.blogspot.de/2006/06/rules-for-long-s.html) has a nice extensive survey of the usage of *ſ* and *s* in old texts.

As to why your author (or typesetter) decided to write *ampliſsimo, cõſeſsui* but *eſſe* and *neceſſum* is difficult to say without more example text. My best guess is that it was a fluke, arbitrary, or because the typesetter run out of one ligature glyph. However, it may also be that the writer considered that the *ſs* in *ampliſsimo* and *cõſeſsui* is positioned towards the end of a syllable or morpheme, while the *ſſ* in *eſſe* and *neceſſum* is not. The usage of *eﬆ* instead of *eﬅ* hints at a paradigm of that sort being employed here (in particular if *ﬅ* is used at the beginning of words). However, to arrive at a useful conclusion, you have to look at more example words.

<sup>Source: For my work on a blackletter font (see my profile) and a user-friendly and correct long-s rule set for the German language, I looked at various old texts in that regard and also consumed a lot of information on the history of the Germanletter *ß.* The aforementioned blog post should also confirm many things.</sup>

---

<sup>¹ e.g., there are English texts in which *husband* is written exactly like this, probably because the typesetter did not have an *ſb* ligature available and also wanted to avoid a large gap between *ſ* and *b* – which becomes evident through the word being hyphenated *huſ-band.*</sup>